# How to get mysql config file path from sql(not from shell)?

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to get the mysql config file path,such as the content of "--defaults-file" as below:

`apps      82357  80311  0  2016 ?        04:59:36 /apps/xx/mariadb/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/apps/xx/mariadb/etc/mariadb3306.cnf --basedir=/apps/xx/mariadb --port=3306`

It is easy to get it from shell,but Is there any way to get it from sql or jdbc?

Comment: You mean [`SHOW VARIABLES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-variables.html)?

Comment: any kind of sql

Comment: That is a kind of SQL. Try it out.

Comment: You can find anything from "SHOW VARIABLES" but cnf file path